# I may have sent a lot of personal information to a scammer via email

Tags: scams, identity-theft

Yes, I know. I'm an idiot. As a very young person who doesn't have much experience with anything, I almost fell into debt from a scammer. I didn't, but I gave them a lot of my personal information. I should've been suspicious when they said the word "kindly" multiple times...Here is what I gave them:

- Email
- Address
- Full Name
- Resume
- Mobile Number
- Age
- Name of the Bank
- My student ID
- Photo of a receipt
- Photo of my signature on the back of a check

I'm extremely worried... this is my first time being scammed, what should I be doing besides reporting this to the FTC and my school? Should I be extremely worried about possible identity theft or using my signature?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you should be worried. Here's what I would do.

1. Notify your bank immediately of what happened so they can put anti-fraud measures in place.
2. Call a major credit bureau and ask them to put a freeze on your credit. it is free and helps block people from opening new lines of credit in your name.
3. File a police report. They aren't going to catch the guy, but it may help if you have documentation of a crime in case you need to prove to someone your identity was compromised. For example, if they find a way to charge things in your name and the creditor tries to argue it was you that did it.

Answer (score 2):

If you close your account with your bank and move your money to a new bank, then at least the scammer's knowledge of your old bank's name will no longer be a threat.

Comment: Be sure to tell the old bank you think the account has been compromised.

Answer (score 1):

You have given them a very good identity fraud kit there - name, address, bank details, photograph, signature, and so on.  All the things that would be needed as proof of identity when opening an account somewhere.